# How do I get the source system timestamp in a stored procedure instead of the SQL Server timestamp?

Tags: sql-server

I am working on the qualification of a SQL Server database used to generate a batch record of a filling machine. The machine is running a Rockwell PLC and the server is using FactoryTalk Transaction Manager to link the PLC and the database.

The database is using stored procedures to populate tables.

The development team used `GETDATE()` to store the times of a record in the stored procedures. But `GETDATE()` is returning the time of the SQL Server not of the source system, the Rockwell PLC.

How can I record the time from the source system?

I want to log the time when a data point is read.

Comment: Not quite sure what your saying here, however, I *assume* what you're asking is how do you get the time of the client, not the time at the server? If you need to store the client time's, you need to tell the server what that time is (so instead of using `GETDATE()` pass the client's time as a parameter to the Stored Procedure). The SQL Server has no context of where (or "when") the client is; it simply knows where it has been told it is, and what the time it currently thinks it is. Or (possibly the better solution), store all your times as `UTC` and convert them to the client's upon retrieval.

Comment: Edit: I just fleshed out the language to make the distinction between the different systems in play a little more clear, and to clarify what the OP is looking for help with.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. so yes, for now, everything is set up as `UTC` and the server is the TimeMaster. so I don't have discrepancies. but my concern is that I am not storing the client's timestamp. So in terms of data integrity, is this important? and so I was wondering if it existed a way to get the client timestamp.